# Bootstrap .modal('show') issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap modal is not working properly that it doesn't add the modal-open class to the body tag.

So I have a button which on clicks does this

```
$('#student-password-change-modal').modal('show');
```

Inside that modal I have a link which does this

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#email-password-change-modal">
Open new modal
</a>
```

When the first modal is opened it adds the modal-open class properly to the body tag but when the second modal is opened it doesn't adds it.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: If you want to open two models, hide the first one before opening the second one.

Comment: yes that's why I have data-dismiss="modal" on the opening tag of the new one

Comment: give a different z-index value to both models.Give lower z-index to the modal you want to show on top

Comment: @mohsinali1317 z-index might solve your problem as MohitHarshan said. Can you create a js fiddle?

Comment: I have tried z-index but it has nothing to do with z-index as far as i know

Comment: have you tried it using $('#yourmodel').modal('hide') instead of data-dismiss

Comment: yes I have tried it.